# What is the term used for this type of biscuit

Tags: cookies

What name is given to the type of cookie that has no icing? 
Wanted the correct term to find on the internet the type of cookie that receives a mark like the figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site. The term you are looking for is [cookie stamp](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=cookie%20stamp) or [biscuit stamp](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=biscuit%20stamp).

You can also get a [cookie press](https://www.thespruceeats.com/best-cookie-presses-4684433), which is like a big glue-gun for forcing out fancy shapes, but these are not pressed into the top of the biscuit, rather by forcing the cookie batter through a template. If you have kids, you will be familiar with plastic versions of these for use with play-dough.

Comment: The poster is asking what the term for the cookie is, not the tool used to make it.

Comment: @GdD - yes, asking the name of the type of cookie, but you will notice the following phrase `Wanted the correct term to find on the internet the type of cookie that receives a mark like the figure:` so my interpretation was that they were looking for the name of how you do this sort of marking, not the name of the actual cookie, because you can use a huge range of different batters for this, and I don't think there is a single name for cookies that are stamped. My personal favourite batter is [Sable].(https://www.joyofbaking.com/Sables.html).

Comment: @bob1 on the other hand, the suitable types of cookies to use with a cookie stamp is rather limited - getting the tool and then using it with a random cookie recipe is likely to result in a disappointment. (E.g. due to spreading or rising that causes the pattern to blur or even disappear.)

Answer (score 2):

You would be looking for a sugar cookie recipe to use with a stamp like that. Sugar cookies tend to hold their shape through a bake, so the imprint will still be clearly visible afterwards.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question @Johanna, the poster wants to know what they are called, not what type of recipe to use. This would be better as a comment.

Comment: @GdD The OP literally asks for the kind of cookie that can get marks like that. Not for the equipment, but for the name of the biscuit/cookie.

Answer (score 1):

iPressed cookies are usually a type of **shortbread cookie**

The flavors vary, and particular ones may have cinnamon, cardamon, citrus, anything really.

The specific cookie that you show has Portuguese writing on it "sweets form heaven". Maybe the name of a bakery in Brazil or Portugal?